# Can In turn offerte AWS Cloudwatch completely?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I am basically playing around trying to understand some things AWS has to offer.
However, since I turned on auto-scaling in DynamoDB I found out that CloudWatch was also joining in.
I noticed that when I looked at my billing overview.

I'm not interested in using CloudWatch (just yet), so I also don't want to pay for it. Can I turn the monitoring off so it doesn't cost me?

I only found answers to silence of hide the alarms. But that still costs money.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't turn it off... the CloudWatch metrics and alarms are what DynamoDB uses to trigger scaling.

> DynamoDB will then monitor throughput consumption using Amazon CloudWatch alarms and then will adjust provisioned capacity up or down as needed.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/

CloudWatch also has a [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/).

Comment: Is there a way to use DynamoDB scaling within the free tier?